# Python Pytest mocking three functions

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

So I am quite new to mocking. I think I need to mock two functions.

Function under test

```
def get_text_from_pdf(next_pdfs_path):
    # TODO test this function
    """
    pulls all text from a PDF document and returns as a string.
            Parameters:
                    next_pdfs_path (str): file path use r"" around path.
            Returns:
                    text (str): string of text
    """
    if os.path.isfile(next_pdfs_path):      # check file is a real file/filepath
        try:
            text = ''
            with fitz.open(next_pdfs_path) as doc:      # using PyMuPDF
                for page in doc:
                    text += page.getText()
            return text
        except (RuntimeError, IOError):
            pass
    pass
```

test code first try

```
from unittest import mock

@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.open", return_value='fake_file.csv', autospec=True)
def test_get_text_from_pdf(mock_fitz_open):
    assert cp.get_text_from_pdf('fake_file.csv') == 'fake_file.csv'
```

error

```
E       AssertionError: assert None == 'fake_file.csv'
E        +  where None = <function get_text_from_pdf at 0x00000245EDF8CAF0>('fake_file.csv')
E        +    where <function get_text_from_pdf at 0x00000245EDF8CAF0> = cp.get_text_from_pdf
```

Do I need to mock both `fitz.open` and `os.path.isfile`? How could that be done if yes?

**EDIT**

Following njriasan feedback I have tried this

```
@mock.patch("content_production.os.path.isfile", return_value=True, autospec=True)
@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.Page.getText")
@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.open")
def test_get_text_from_pdf(mock_fitz_open, mock_path_isfile, mock_gettext):
    mock_fitz_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = 'test'
    assert cp.get_text_from_pdf('test') == 'test'
```

But now getting this error.

```
>                       text += page.getText()
E                       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple issues with what you are doing. The first problem I see is that I think you are mocking the wrong function. By mocking `fitz.open(next_pdfs_path)` you are still expecting:

```py
for page in doc:
    text += page.getText()
```

to execute properly. I'd suggest that you wrap this entire with statement and text result updating in a helper function and then mock that. If the file path doesn't actually exist on your system then you will also need to mock `os.path.isfile`. I believe that can be done by adding a second decorator (I don't think there is any limit).

Comment: Can I not just mock all three functions? ```isfile()```, ```open()``` and ```gettext()``` and skip the helper function or is that not possible?

Comment: You could mock all three that's fine. You will need to ensure open returns an iterable for  the line. To clarify, you need all non-mocked code, in this case:
```python
for page in doc:
```
to execute properly

The only additional issue that may arise is that you need to mock the import location.
So if you do something inside example.py that says `from module import func`, you would need to make sure to mock example.func, not module.func.